# use of rotation vector sensor

Tags: android, rotation, android-sensors, quaternions

I want to implement *rotation vector* sensor. I searched as much as I could about this sensor but I confused some points. I understand that I need to use *quaternions* other than *Euler* angles for my app to be more stable. I will use this sensor datas for gesture recognition. So I want to use *quaternions* but I don’t understand how can I convert them to *quaternions* after using *remapCoordinateSystem* method? Or am I wrong about what I want to do? Even a little bit help will be very useful for me.

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    float[] rotationMatrix = new float[9];
    SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(rotationMatrix, event.values);

    float[] adjustedRotationMatrix = new float[9];
    SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(rotationMatrix, SensorManager.AXIS_X, SensorManager.AXIS_Z, adjustedRotationMatrix);

    float[] orientation = new float[3];
    SensorManager.getOrientation(adjustedRotationMatrix, orientation);
    float pitch = orientation[1];
    float roll = orientation[2];
    float yaw = orientation[0];

    yawTextView.setText(getResources().getString(
            R.string.yaw_sensor,yaw));
    pitchTextView.setText(getResources().getString(
            R.string.pitch_sensor,pitch));
    rollTextView.setText(getResources().getString(
            R.string.roll_sensor,roll));

}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Euler angles to quaternion conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles#Euler_angles_to_quaternion_conversion).

Or otherwise, if you'd like to calculate quaternion components directly from the rotation matrix, see [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Quaternion).